# Checks if a div is visible when not behind a overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a page with a overlay (making the loading effect) with a content div behind. I want to trigger a function when the content div (id content-to-test) is visible on the screen (when the loading goes invisible).

I'm using the .is(':visible') jQuery function but this function only checks the div visibility or display.

I need to check when the content div is visible to the user

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="overlay">
            <br><br>
            <img src="http://www.cariblist.com/loader/new_loading2.gif" style="width: 80px; margin-left: 40%;" />
        </div>
        <div id="content-to-test">
            <br>This is the content
        </div>
    </div>
```

The full example: https://jsfiddle.net/42qw0uzf/1/
Click on "Toggle overlay visibility" or/and "Toggle content visibility" to check the label "Content is: " state (VISIBLE or INVISIBLE)

Comment: So if I understand correct, you want to check of there is an overlay visible and is overlapping current div. Right?

Comment: Not an accurate question, please define your goal better. Should it be in viewport or completely visible, or?

Comment: Can't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: Set a timer, checking for 2 conditions: overlay is invisible + content is visible. If both requirements check out, trigger the functions u need.

Comment: Can't see the problem. The content div is correctly reported to be visible in your code, whether I make the overlay visible or invisible.

Comment: I want to be able to check if the #content-to-test is visible or not. By visible I mean that the #content-to-test is not overlapped by the overlay